# How to read each character from string in C#

Tags: c#, string, compiler-construction

What I want to do is to code a program that takes file input or user input of string and check character by character if space or double/single quotation come in string then break it and make a separate string of that word.
I used Split function to break words in string according to given delimiters. But my code isn't working for word enclosed in quotations.
Actually, this task is related with Compiler Construction course.

For example:

User input: `sjhdfn"ff"fgfgfg".'\nff' 'f'`

Output of words should be:
`sjhdfn`         //ID

`"ff"fgfgfg"`    //String

`\n`             //Character = new line

`ff`             //ID

`'f'`            //Char

Can anyone help to code string part of output with double quotations?

Comment: three quote-signs with those in the middle unmasked? I don't think it's a valid syntax, and if it is, `check character by character if space or double/single quotation come in string then break it` is not enough. Actually, this scenario creates ambiguities, that can't be handled without additional rules

Comment: And if task is related to compiler construction course, i strongly suggest you to learn at least what's `Parse tree`. Parsing non-complicated "code" to it is not hard, but it's very handy.

Comment: Hi Zloidooraque,

Thanks for your comment. Don't worry about syntax, I just want output in the form I mentioned in my question description. I'm at the initial stage of CC where I don't need to take care of Semantic error, I just need to break each word as soon as desired wordBreaker comes in string. 
As soon as, double quote comes in string, break the previous character sequence with it and make a word, then start a new word including double quote open and closing closed. Whatever comes in between, just print it.

Comment: as you may guess, odd number of double quotation marks is allowed only if dobule quotation is itself inside quotes `'"'`. and you have three d.quotations. it's automatically error. single quot.marks number also must be even for those quotation marks that are outside double quotation blocks (not belonging to words).

Comment: if it is guaranteed, that input string is always valid, the task is simple: trim() input string, see if 1st symbol is d.quotation, split by d.quotations (with option for keeping empty substrings turned on in `Split`), if 1st symbol was d.quotation, all odd items (0,2,4..) in resulting collection are strings, if not, all even items are strings. find "\n" in them. split remaining substrings with quotation marks: use the same algorithm as for d.quotations and you will find `char`s. split all that remains with `space` and you have your `ID`s

Comment: You need a lexer/scanner/tokenizer.  It is a simple state machine.  Have a look at http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cse756/html/cse756se2.html from about 2.8 onwards.  It may be an ancient technique since nobody teaches state machines anymore but it is still one of the fastest techniques available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`foreach(char c in s)`

or `for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) DoSomething(s[i])`,

but as I said in comments, the problem lies elsewhere. Of course `Split` will break your so-called "word" in two, if it has double quotation mark in it's delimiters list.

Comment: I have tried both loop but they aren't giving desired output. I want to add double quotes as well in word as compiler is considering it as string.